# ATG 11 server and DB configuration

Tags: atg

Which database and server is mandatory to run any ATG HelloWorld or ATG demo application? I'd like to run it and I have hard time with the configuration. Can someone point me which steps are mandatory after running the cim script?

#### Architecture

```
ATG 11 
Windows 7 
Weblogic 12
MySql (shipped with Web Commerce pack)
```

#### script

```
C:\ATG\ATG11.0\home\bin\cim.bat
```

#### which DB configuration?

```
[R] Reporting Data Warehouse
[L] Reporting Loader
[P] Publishing
[C] Production Core
[S] Staging
```

#### which server configuration?

```
[W] Data Warehouse Loader Server
[P] Production Lock Manager Server
[S] Production Server
[C] Commerce Only SSO Server
[T] Staging Server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a Storefront instance

`[C] Production Core`

and you need to configure it as a

`[S] Production Server`

Comment: To run the full ATG Demo or Commerce Reference Store, you would have to have a publishing instance as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'll briefly explain why the above modules answered by radimpe are sufficient to run Helloworld and ATG Demo applications such as crs.

Production core contains the core schema. For practice you can import any one of the cata/catb schemas to load the product catalog into Production core. In case if you want to work on publishing and merchandising modules, I would recommend you to configure Publishing DB Configuration as well.

Regarding server configuration, Production Server is suffice. Lock Manager, Staging servers will be configured in Production and lower environments.

If you want to install ATG for practice, refer the link which explains the step-by-step procedure of ATG10.0.3 installation for production schema. Almost all ATG11 installation procedure remains same.

http://www.harshavmb.com/oracle-atg-10-installation/

Comment: I would recommend caution with your last statement: ATG 10.0.x uses ATG Search and not Endeca.  ATG 11 does away with ATG Search and uses Endeca exclusively.

Comment: @bated..sorry for that.  You are correct..  ATG11 works only with Endeca search as ATG search is rolled out..